# rcharts nPlot not recognizing quarter values on x-axis

Tags: r, rcharts

Still very new to using rCharts and R, so please excuse me if the question sounds very stupid!

I'm trying to plot a time series chart using Quarter labels along the x-axis, simple example:

```
quarters <- c("Q413","Q313","Q213","Q13")
values <- c("120","40","60","80")
testing = data.frame(quarters,values)
tfrPlot <- nPlot(x="quarter", y="values", data = testing, type = "lineChart")
```

But this doesn't plot the graph and instead generates value between -1 and 1 on the x-axis. I made sure the quarters were factors as well, so I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The error is primarily caused by a typo `x="quarter` which should be `x=quarters`, but even with this we will have errors.  nvd3 with lineChart expects y to be numeric or continuous, so `values<-as.numeric(c("120","40","60","80"))` will also be required.  Then one last thing the date conversion from R to Javascript in rCharts is [still not optimal](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/43).  One way to force it to work would be to pass the date in numeric form and then tell nvd3 how to handle it.  Here is an example:

```
quarters <- as.Date(c("2013-03-31", "2013-06-30", "2013-09-30", "2013-12-31"))
values <- as.numeric(c("120","40","60","80"))
testing = data.frame(quarters,values)
tfrPlot <- nPlot(x="quarters", y="values", data = testing, type = "lineChart")
tfrPlot$xAxis(
  tickFormat = 
    "#! function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(new Date(d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    } !#"
)
tfrPlot
```

You will probably agree this is more painful than it should be, and we are working on a much better way to handle this.